# How to get value and id_value for PushRow in Swift4

Tags: swift4, eureka-forms

I use xCode 9, swift 4 and "Eureka form library" for my project.

**The situation**

I have a list of cars with name and unique ID associated this way:  0 - ANY, 1 - VW, 7 - AUDI, 20 - MAZDA

```
var name_cars: [String] = ["ANY","VW","AUDI","MAZDA"]

var id_cars:[Int] = [0, 1, 7, 20]
```

I also have a form with "PushRow" and "ButtonRow".
On click to the button I want to print the selected car name and ID.
I was able to print the car's name but not the ID.

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

class myPage: FormViewController {

    var cars: [String] = ["ANY","VW","AUDI","MAZDA"]
    var id_cars:[Int] = [0, 1,7,20]

    var selected_car: String = "ANY" //default car
    var selected_car_id: Int = 0 //default id car

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        create_form()
    }

    func create_form(){

        form
        +++ Section("List")

        //list
        <<< PushRow<String>() {
            $0.title = "Cars"
            $0.options = cars
            $0.value = "ANY"

            $0.tag = "list_element"
            $0.selectorTitle = "Choose car"
            $0.onChange { [unowned self] row in
                self.selected_car = row.value!
                self.selected_car_id = ??? // **what should it be here in order to get the ID**
            }

        }

        //button
        <<< ButtonRow("Button1") {row in
            row.title = "Get Value on Console"
            row.onCellSelection{[unowned self] ButtonCellOf, row in
                print ("Car selected = ",self.selected_car, " and Id_Car_Selected = ",self.selected_car_id)
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all please conform to the naming convention that class names start with a capital letter and variable names are *lowerCamelCased* rather than *snake_cased*.

Swift is an object oriented language. Rather than two separate arrays use a custom struct `Car`.

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

struct Car : Equatable {
    let name : String
    let id : Int
}
```

The push row is declared as `PushRow<Car>()` and the property `displayValueFor` is populated with the name

```
class MyPage: FormViewController {

    let cars = [Car(name: "ANY", id: 0), Car(name: "VW", id: 1), Car(name: "AUDI", id: 7), Car(name: "MAZDA", id: 20)]

    var selectedCar : Car!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        selectedCar = cars[0]
        createForm()
    }


    func createForm() {

        form
            +++ Section("List")

            //list
            <<< PushRow<Car>() {
                $0.title = "Cars"
                $0.options = cars
                $0.value = selectedCar
                $0.displayValueFor = {
                    guard let car = $0 else { return nil }
                    return car.name
                }

                $0.tag = "list_element"
                $0.selectorTitle = "Choose car"
                $0.onChange { [unowned self] row in
                    self.selectedCar = row.value!
                }

            }

            //button
            <<< ButtonRow("Button1") {row in
                row.title = "Get Value on Console"
                row.onCellSelection{[unowned self] ButtonCellOf, row in
                    print ("Car selected = ", self.selectedCar.name, " and Id_Car_Selected = ", self.selectedCar.id)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your example works perfect. However I have one question: can you elaborate about the functionality of "dispalyValueFor"?

Comment: As the array of `options` is an array of `Car` rather than an array of `String` the `displayValueFor` property specifies which arbitrary value of the `Car` instance is displayed to the user, in this case the `name` property.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.